# System Verilog: enum inside interface

Tags: interface, enums, system-verilog

I have an interface:

```
interface my_intf();
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
   VAL_0 = 2'b00,
   VAL_1 = 2'b01,
   VAL_2 = 2'b10,
   VAL_3 = 2'b11
} T_VAL;
T_VAL val;
endinterface
```

My module uses this interface:

```
my_intf intf;
```

The problem is to assign the `val` with a value from the `enum`.

I can assign it as:

`intf.val = 0;` (and receiving warning or error)

but not as:

`intf.val=VAL_0;`

Nor as

`intf.val = my_intf.T_VAL.VAL_0`

How I overcome that problem?

Comment: For the record, the last syntax works with Vivado only if `val` is in the modport list, that is employed by the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only dealt with packages for containing enums before, and avoid interfaces. This is how I use packages. Import the package before the module definition with which you want to use it:

```
import my_intf_pkg::* ;

module bla(
  output my_val_t intf
);

  initial begin
    intf = VAL_0 ;
  end

endmodule
```

The package containing enums might look like:

```
package my_intf_pkg;
  typedef enum logic [1:0] {
     VAL_0 = 2'b00,
     VAL_1 = 2'b01,
     VAL_2 = 2'b10,
     VAL_3 = 2'b11
  } my_val_t;
endpackage : my_intf_pkg
```

Note that the `VAL_0` etc are global and not tied to the `T_VAL` typedef. Therefore I often make them a bit more unique including the typedef in the name. `T_VAL_0` for `T_VAL` typedefs etc.

[Here is an example on EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2tk).

Comment: There is an elaboration error for the "my_intf.sv": The type name 'T_VAL' is unknown.

Comment: Try to use it in the interface: 
`interface my_intf();
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
   VAL_0 = 2'b00,
   VAL_1 = 2'b01,
   VAL_2 = 2'b10,
   VAL_3 = 2'b11
} T_VAL;
T_VAL val;
endinterface`

Comment: Try defining the enum outside of the interface as I have done for the module, and import it.

Comment: @Michael, Sometimes Verilog just feels like jumping through arbitrary hoops.

Answer (score 1):

`intf.val = 0;` should be an error because you are trying to assign a integral type to an enum without a cast.

`intf.val = VAL_0;` is an error because VAL_0 is not defined in the current scope.

You should be able to do

```
intf.val = intf.VAL_0;
```

However, the best solution in to put shared types in a package, an import the package where needed.

Comment: `intf.val = intf.VAL_0;` is not working - vcs is not supporting it.

Comment: @Michael be sure to raise a case with Synopsys!